# Searching on timestamp created on the fly in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have external ES instance which I need to query for documents older than 6 months. Problem is they store timestamp like that:

```
"timestamp": {
            "year": 2018,
            "monthValue": 5,
            "dayValue": 1,
    }
```

Is it possible to create a range query combining these fields and getting documents "lt" "now-6m" or something like that?

Comment: Very unlikely. `now-6m` can only be used on `date` fields. You can do a combination of `range` queries on those fields, but it will be pretty convoluted... Best is to add a real date field.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using a [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).  That would enable you to create a date object using the field values, and then compare that date with the current date.

**Notional example**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "params": {
              "monthRange": 6
            },
            "source": """
              def today = new Date();
              def timestamp = new Date(doc['timestamp']['year'].value, doc['timestamp']['monthValue'].value, doc['timestamp']['dayValue'].value);

              /* Date comparison magic (I don't know Java, so you're on your own here) */

              /* return result of comparison */
            """,
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've only used [Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html) once before, so I'm not familiar enough to give a perfect answer.  But this may help you get started.  If you get stuck, just ask another question specific to the issue you're having, and someone who's more familiar with Java/Painless can help you out.